# Loading CSV from remote file

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am writing the following code from a CSV to get stock data, When I have downloaded the string it is splitting it in the following way

```
<COMPANY NAME>,<STOCK PRICE>,<STOCK CHANGE>
<COMPANY2 NAME>,<STOCK PRICE2>,<STOCK CHANGE2>
```

I have tried to split the array by using the /n character using the PHP function explode. However this did not split it properly. Here is my code:

```
public function getQuotes()
{        
    $result = array();      
    $format = $this->format;
    $stockString = "";

    foreach ($this->stocks as $stock)
    { 
        $stockString = $stockString . $stock . "+";
    } 
    //Remove the last "+"
    $stockString = substr($stockString,0,strlen($stockString)-1);
    $s = file_get_contents("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=". $stockString . "&f=" . $format . "&e=.csv");

    //The splitting is to be done here.

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `file` function instead of `file_get_contents` - it will split the content for you, as [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) says:

> Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to
>   a line in the file, with the newline still attached. Upon failure,
>   file() returns FALSE.

Then you can use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) for each element of array to get field values.

```
public function getQuotes()
{        
    $result = array();      
    $format = $this->format;
    $stockString = "";

    foreach ($this->stocks as $stock)
    { 
        $stockString = $stockString . $stock . "+";
    } 
    //Remove the last "+"
    $stockString = substr($stockString,0,strlen($stockString)-1);
    $s = file("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=". $stockString . "&f=" . $format . "&e=.csv");

    foreach($s as $line) {
        $values = str_getcsv($line);
    }
}
```